# Getting information from staticmethod outside of class without its instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with the following method:

```
@staticmethod
def get_values(df: pd.DataFrame, val: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    match val:
        case "mean_2_step":
            return (
                df["mean_2"]
                .shift()
                .rolling(window=10, min_periods=3, closed="right", step=2)
                .mean()
            )
        case "mean_4_step":
            return (
                df["mean_4"]
                .shift()
                .rolling(window=20, min_periods=4, closed="right", step=4)
                .mean()
            )
    return df
```

I would like to get an information from that method, possibly without invoking it. The main purpose of that opearation is to get this information (as a form of documentation) and save it in ReadMe.md, like so:

| val | calculation |
| --- | --- |
| mean_2_step | df["mean_2"].shift().rolling(window=10, min_periods=3, closed="right", step=2).mean() |
| mean_4_step | df["mean_4"].shift().rolling(window=20, min_periods=4, closed="right", step=4).mean() |

How to achieve that?

Comment: you want to populate the `df` without passing that `df` as an argument?

Comment: Do you want `df[val] = <class_name>.get_values(df, val)` or is the dataframe allready an instance value and you potentially want `get_values()` to be an instance method?

Comment: Let's assume the `df` does not exist at all. All i want to do, is to "parse" the information about calculation and put them into a table in .md file without even running this staticmethod.

Comment: Instead of having imperative code (i.e. a function) and extracting declarative data (i.e. a list or dict) out of it, reorganize the code so that there is publicly available declarative data which is also used within the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to parse the function source code (body) to get the info of specific nodes `match_case`s in form *<*match pattern: match body*>*.
The [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) modules are best for that.
Assuming that your class is called say `MyClass`.
The algorithm is as follows:

- get the source code of the function object with `inspect.getsource`
- correct indentations with [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to prepare for further parsing
- parse the source into an *`AST`* node with `ast.parse`
- walking over descendant nodes with `ast.walk` while filtering only the needed type of nodes [`ast.match_case`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.match_case)
- mine the node attribute textual values to fill the final dataframe

---

```
import inspect
import ast
import textwrap

src = textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(MyClass.get_values))
pat = re.compile(r'\s{2,}|\n', flags=re.M) # patern for eliminating extra whitespaces
match_cases = (n for n in ast.walk(ast.parse(src)) if isinstance(n, ast.match_case))

df = pd.DataFrame([[n.pattern.value.value,
                    pat.sub('', ast.get_source_segment(src, n.body[0].value))]
                   for n in match_cases], columns=['val', 'calcuation'])
print(df)
```

---

```
           val                                                                             calcuation
0  mean_2_step  df["mean_2"].shift().rolling(window=10, min_periods=3, closed="right", step=2).mean()
1  mean_4_step  df["mean_4"].shift().rolling(window=20, min_periods=4, closed="right", step=4).mean()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much.